# rvest Scrape all values from website by specific class

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest

I am trying to scrape all location numbers, street address, and city/state/zip from this website. I have tried a few different approaches, unsuccessfully, including trying to extract the value from a specific class. By digging through the source code, I found that the three values I need have the following classes `css-dhj0hp, css-8er82g, css-n2nvu7`. Ideally, I'd want a dataframe with store number, street address, city, state, zip but I can't even get the text to return. Can someone help?

```
library(rvest)
library(tidyverse)

url <- "https://locations.wafflehouse.com"

page <- read_html(url)

store_data <- 
  page |> 
  html_nodes("div.css-dhj0hp")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> /../ By digging through the source code /../

You probably refer to *Element Inspector* which happens to be quite a different beast. It lets you navigate through DOM tree that for dynamic sites is rendered or at least heavily modified by Javascript and can be quite different from the content `rvest` tries to parse.

In the actual page source, webapp data along with locations are embedded in the `<script id="__NEXT_DATA__" type="application/json"> .. </script>` element as JSON, we can extract it with `rvest` and parse with `jsonlite`; locations are bit deeper in resulting nested list, `props > pageProps > locations`:

```r
library(rvest)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

url <- "https://locations.wafflehouse.com" 

page <- read_html(url)
store_data <- 
  page |> 
  html_element("script#__NEXT_DATA__") |> 
  html_text() |> 
  jsonlite::fromJSON() |>
  purrr::pluck("props", "pageProps", "locations") |>
  unnest(addressLines) |>
  unnest(custom) |> 
  as_tibble()

glimpse(store_data)
#> Rows: 1,978
#> Columns: 19
#> $ storeCode              <chr> "100", "1000", "1001", "1002", "1003", "1004", …
#> $ businessName           <chr> "Waffle House #100", "Waffle House #1000", "Waf…
#> $ addressLines           <chr> "2842 PANOLA RD", "2840 E. COLLEGE AVE.", "1292…
#> $ city                   <chr> "LITHONIA", "DECATUR", "LOUISVILLE", "NORMAN", …
#> $ state                  <chr> "GA", "GA", "KY", "OK", "MS", "AL", "GA", "MO",…
#> $ country                <chr> "US", "US", "US", "US", "US", "US", "US", "US",…
#> $ operated_by            <chr> "WAFFLE HOUSE, INC", "WAFFLE HOUSE, INC", "FULL…
#> $ online_order_link      <chr> NA, "https://order.wafflehouse.com/menu/waffle-…
#> $ postalCode             <chr> "30058", "30030", "40243", "73072", "39520", "3…
#> $ latitude               <dbl> 33.70471, 33.77522, 38.24359, 35.23244, 30.3132…
#> $ longitude              <dbl> -84.16985, -84.27374, -85.51321, -97.48904, -89…
#> $ phoneNumbers           <list> "(770) 981-1914", "(404) 294-8758", "(502) 244…
#> $ websiteURL             <chr> "https://locations.wafflehouse.com///lithonia-g…
#> $ businessHours          <list> <"00:00", "00:00", "00:00", "00:00", "00:00", …
#> $ specialHours           <list> <NULL>, <NULL>, <NULL>, <NULL>, <NULL>, <NULL>…
#> $ formattedBusinessHours <list> "Monday - Sunday| 24 hours", "Monday - Sunday|…
#> $ slug                   <chr> "lithonia-ga-100", "decatur-ga-1000", "louisvil…
#> $ localPageUrl           <chr> "/lithonia-ga-100", "/decatur-ga-1000", "/louis…
#> $ `_status`              <chr> "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A…
```

<sup>Created on 2023-08-20 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>